# JS - Add Class to link that contains a certain word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use Jquery to add a class to all links which contain a certain keyword "keyword".
Any help would be much appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.list').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.text().indexOf('Keyword') > -1)
                $this.closest('.list a').addClass('selected-link')
            })  
         })
```

```css
.selected-link {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#">Keyword</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need find a inside li tag as `$this.find('a')`, `$this.text()` is content of li tag

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.list').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.find('a').text().indexOf('Keyword') > -1)
                $this.find('a').addClass('selected-link')
            })  
         })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#">Keyword</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `.list a`s instead - the `<a>`s which are descendants from the `.list`:

```js
$('.list a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text().indexOf('Keyword') > -1) {
    $this.addClass('selected-link');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Keyword</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that there's no need for a big library like jQuery for something this trivial, this is easy to accomplish in vanilla JS:

```js
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('.list a')) {
  if (a.textContent.includes('Keyword')) {
    a.classList.add('selected-link');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Keyword</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {   
  document.querySelectorAll('.list a').forEach(el=>
    {
    if (/Keyword/.test(el.textContent) )
      { el.classList.add('selected-link') } 
    })
  })
```

```css
.selected-link {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#">Keyword</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```